# Getting this error - "Handler "iisnode" has a bad module "iisnode" in its module list"

Tags: c#, iis, azure, socket.io, iisnode

I am trying to implement socket.io in my azure project. I followed the instructions mentioned here https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode to install iisnode on my windows 8. Everything installed fine and the sample node.js app which comes with iisnode here `http://localhost/node/helloworld/hello.js` is running fine too.

But when i run my App.js in the azure project on my VS 2012 , i get the error "Handler "iisnode" has a bad module "iisnode" in its module list". It has been very frustrating.

Web Config

```
 <add name="iisnode" path="App.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
```

Does anyone what the problem can be? Any ideas at all would be deeply appreciated....i have been struck at this all day.

[image: error]

EDIT:

My application was running on iis express so I installed IISNode for IIS Express from Web Platform Installer. But i think IISNode for IIS express is available only for x86 becasue it was looking for node.js in my Program File(x86) so i had to install the x86 version of node.js even though my system is 64bit. After that socket.io is working, but when i open my App.js in browser which contains socket.io implementation i get the following error. Should i be concerned about this error? because socket.io implementation is working fine
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may indicate a mismatch of bitness between the IIS worker process you are running your application in and the bitness of the installed version of iisnode.

What version of iisnode do you have and how was it installed on the machine? How is the node.js application hosted (IIS Express or full IIS)?

Comment: I installed the "iisnode-full-iis7-v0.2.3-x64.msi". Node.js application is hosted in IIS express. How can i check the bitness of the iis worker process?

Comment: I just ran the .msi file. and iisnode version is 0.2.3, node version is v0.8.21

Comment: I have updated the question, can u please answer to it! Thanks a lot

Comment: I have been facing problem with running the node js script on an azure cloud project. It runs fine on web role but doesnt work when its hosted on the local emulator. What can be the issue? Please refer to my questiosn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223683/xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-er) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244558/how-to-start-node-js-script-in-a-windows-azure-cloud-project)