# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Tags: javascript, networking, azure, xmlhttprequest, socket.io

I am using socket.io for a windows azure project. Strangely the socket.io server starts when i just deploy the web role but when i deploy the whole cloud project, the socket.io server doesnt start and i get this error -

```
"SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd."
```

I have absolutely no idea what that means. Can anyone help me out on this one? I have been banging my head about it all day.

SocketClient.html

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:4001');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);       
});

$(function () {
    $("#sendresponse").bind("click", function () {
     socket.emit('server', 'Hello World');

    });
}
);
</script>
```

App.js

```
var app = require('express')(), server = require('http').createServer(app), io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(4001);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'first time connect' });
socket.on('server', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('news',"hello");
});
});
```

Comment: ERROR_INTERNET_REQUEST_PENDING, "The required operation could not be completed because one or more requests are pending".

Comment: What does that mean in my socket.io context?

Comment: And how can i fix it?

Comment: It looks like this error is coming because the socket.io server is not running when am hosting it on local emulator. Socket.io starts fine when am just running the web role on iis express. Anyone has any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that the App.js script was not running when i deployed the cloud project, i.e the iisnode handler which i had put in my web.config wasnt doing its job when the whole cloud project was deployed. After going through this [article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/) i found out that i had to put some files in my bin folder of web role namely - ChangeConfig.ps1,download.ps1,node.cmd,setup_web.cmd. you can generate these files when you go through that article. And finally you have to put this code in your ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<Startup>      
 <Task commandLine="setup_web.cmd &gt; log.txt" executionContext="elevated">
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="EMULATED">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
      </Variable>
      <Variable name="RUNTIMEID" value="node;iisnode" />
      <Variable name="RUNTIMEURL" value="" />
    </Environment>
  </Task>
</Startup>
```

And voila!! It works like a charm. You would still have to start the socket.io server by running 127.0.0.1/App.js on browser. I am still looking at how to start App.js programattically.